# Лямбда выражения в c# ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, лямбда-выражение

В учебном материале есть такой листинг:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Редактировать книгу";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@model BookStore.Models.Book
<h2>Книга № @Model.Id</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditBook", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <fieldset>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
...
```

Интересует меня только последняя строчка `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)`: Как компилятор(или другое магическое существо) понимает что m это именно модель?

Comment: [Html.HiddenFor](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/InputExtensions.cs#L133)

Comment: Вы же тип модели сами указали выше `@model BookStore.Models.Book`